# Wait_for and buttons not working for discord bot

Tags: python, button, discord

I am trying to make something that is whenever someone clicks on a button, the bot will send another message.

I searched online and found lots of libraries but every time I try it says interaction failed.

It seems the bot never gets to the wait_for part in halloween.py, and I am wondering if I did anything wrong.

[image]

Here is the code for main.py:

```
import json
import random

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

INITIAL_EXTENSIONS = [
    "cogs.default",
    "cogs.halloween"
]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="can ")
client = discord.Client()
bot.remove_command("help")


def percentage(percentage):
    raw = []
    for x in range(percentage):
        raw.append(1)

    for y in range(100 - percentage):
        raw.append(0)

    selected = random.choice(raw)
    if selected == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def read_JSON(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return json.load(f)


for extension in INITIAL_EXTENSIONS:
    try:
        bot.load_extension(extension)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to load extension {}\n{}: {}'.format(extension, type(e).__name__, e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(read_JSON("data.json")["TOKEN"])
```

And here is halloween.py:

```
import random
import time

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import *

import main


class Halloween(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def checkdoor(self, ctx):
        someonethere = main.percentage(100)
        await ctx.channel.send("Seeing if anyone is at the door...")
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
        if someonethere:
            give = Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Give", id="result")

            result = discord.Embed(title=f"You gave!", description="Description", colour=discord.Colour.blue())

            await ctx.reply(
                embed=there_embed,
                components=[
                    [give]
                ]
            )

            buttons = {
                "result": result
            }

            def check(m):
                return m.channel == ctx.channel

            while True:
                event = await main.client.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
                if event.channel is not ctx.channel:
                    return
                if event.channel == ctx.channel:
                    response = buttons.get(event.component.id)
                    if response is None:
                        await event.channel.send("Something went wrong. Please try it again")
                    if event.channel == ctx.channel:
                        await event.respond(
                            type=4,
                            embed=response
                        )

        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Nope",
                description="No one's there at your door. Try again later..."
            )

            return await ctx.reply(embed=embed)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Halloween(bot))
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you get a specific error message or traceback error for the bot's terminal?

Comment: No, the only error message is shown on discord, not in the python console